# submit array of inputs using ajax and retrive in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, post

Anyody knows how to get array of post inputs from ajax to CodeIgniter?

E.X.

```
<input name="city[]" value="xxx">
<input name="city[]" value="yyy">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->input->post("city");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar question and solution for multiple fields posting using jQuery Ajax.

[How to pass multiple checkboxes using jQuery ajax post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908708/how-to-pass-multiple-checkboxes-using-jquery-ajax-post)

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!