# my checkbox doest not match the count of data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, checkbox

I made checkbox the data from database and still work, when I click multiple checkbox, the count of data clicked is matches

**result console.log**
[image]

the problem when I sending data to **filter.php** with method post

the count of data received is not matches
[image]
**event click jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#t_pendaftar').DataTable();
                    $('#filter').click(function () {
                     var data = { 'venue[]' : []};
                     var arr = $('.treas:checked').map(function () {
                        data['venue[]'].push($(this).val());
                     }).get();
                     console.log(data);
                     $.post("filter.php",{data : data});
                 });       
                });
```

**filter.php**

```
<?php var_dump($_POST['data']);   if(!empty($_POST['data'])) {
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $check) {
            print_r($check);
     } }   ?>
```

thank you for attention

Comment: Why you do `var data = { 'venue[]' : []};`? Isn't `var data = { 'venue' : []};`  enough?

Comment: @u_mulder ok i will try it :D  I just follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908708/how-to-pass-multiple-checkboxes-using-jquery-ajax-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert json string from javascript object by using `JSON.stringify`.
PHP can refer post data from by decoding json string.

You can get expected results as below code that applied these things.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t_pendaftar').DataTable();
    $('#filter').click(function () {
        var data = { 'venue' : []};
        var arr = $('.treas:checked').map(function () {
            data['venue'].push($(this).val());
        }).get();
        data = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.post("filter.php", {data : data});
    });       
});
```

filter.php:

```
if (!empty($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
    foreach($data['venue'] as $check) {
        print_r($check);
    }
}
```

Comment: @senaa I'm relieved to hear that. could you chose as a good answer?

Comment: btw I want to execute' sql query where in ' how to make it ?  I using implode but not work for string values

Comment: @senaa please try this in order to accept answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: thanks a lot! About your additional question above, please post as new question.